# Передача данный между 2 Raspberry Pi

Tags: ip, raspberry-pi

Есть две `Raspberry Pi` между которыми нужно передавать данный.

Проблема в том что у них динамический `IP` адрес и на данный момент использую для обмена данных `Proxy` на сервере со статикой `IP` но хочется убрать лишнее звено из цепи.

Comment: Расстояние какое между ними? И какие объемы данных...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Raspberry Pi в одном городе, а сервер в Германии, но ping и скорость передачи не критична.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать возможности ddns: каждой малинке присвоить свой доменный адрес, и поднять на них простые демоны (или через крон) для обновления данных в dns. После чего достаточно обращаться к нужной малинке не по ip, а по доменному адресу.

У меня так работает доступ к домашней локальной сети извне. Решение абсолютно бесплатное.

В качестве DDNS-сервера использую http://freedns.afraid.org/ Но это не единственный вариант бесплатного DDNS-сервера.

Comment: DDNS это конечно хорошее решение, только вот насколько надёжен бесплатный сервер? Я имею ввиду что не станет ли он платным или закроется. Ну а других решений особенно и нет наверное, или через сервер, или покупать IP, или через сотовый модем SMS

Comment: Может и станет... Но таких серверов много и я пользуюсь этим уже пару лет... А ещё, если посмотреть их описание, они сами говорят, что сделан сервер именно для того, чтобы сделать эту услугу бесплатной.

Answer (score 0):

ipv6 например через Teredo. Смотрите решение https://habrahabr.ru/post/127405/  использовалось для удаленного управления, но думаю и вам сгодится.